# Apache POI Not Recaclulating

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have a workbook with a large number of formulas, including formulas that depend on the results of other formulas that depend on VLOOKUPs, etc.  All of these lead to the calculation of a single value. When I try to get the value via POI 3.13, it's #VALUE!. However, if I open the workbook in Excel, it's calculated correctly.

Before getting the value I need, I call:

```
book.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
```

Which, according to the documentation, should resolve these issues. [Apache's documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#recalculation) even calls out the #VALUE! issue specifically and suggests the above step as a resolution, yet I can't get it to work. I do not get any formula exceptions.

I've also tried calling evaluateAll() after each time I set a value (about 100 get set for this scenario), still it's #VALUE!

```
    public boolean setValue(final int value, final String tabName, final int rowNum, final int colNum) {
    boolean returnVal;
    try {
        final Cell currentCell = getCell(tabName, rowNum, colNum);
        currentCell.setCellValue(value);
        currentCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
        book.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
        returnVal = true;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception setting value " + value + " on " + tabName + " " + rowNum + "," + colNum, e);
        returnVal = false;
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

The cell in question has this formula:

```
=SUM('VEH1'!H3+'VEH2'!H3+'VEH3'!H3+'VEH4'!H3)
```

All of the cells, like 'VEH1'!H3, have similar formulas that deal with their specific sheet:

```
=IF('VEH1'!B10>0,SUM(H11:W11),0)
```

Where the value in 'VEH1'!B10 is 1 through 4. H11 through W11 are also formula cells, such as:

```
=H71+H40
```

H71 is this:

```
=ROUND(H69*H39,2)
```

And so on down a chain of dollar values multipled times some factor value. Factor values are found mainly via lookups:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($C26,LookupTable,3,FALSE)),1,VLOOKUP($C26,LookupTable,3,FALSE))
```

Where **LookupTable** in the above is a named sub table on another worksheet.  Lookups often are based on the values of either A) what the user (or POI, in this case) entered in a cell, or B) a combination of several cells that POI entered, like =B1&B2&B3&B4

Each of the steps is repeated dozens of times. Basically, I get the sum of 16 values where each of those 16 is the sum of 52 rows, about half of which are lookups (many with various IF conditional logic pieces as well), the other half pretty simple =ROUND(A1*B1,2) formulas.

It appears to be only the last step that fails, the formula:

```
=SUM('VEH1'!H3+'VEH2'!H3+'VEH3'!H3+'VEH4'!H3)
```

Comment: Other than a possible pointer to a logged issue in POI, it's going to be rather hard for anyone to help without sample data that replicates the problem.

Comment: And of course I can't post that as it's company trade data, sorry. What is the logged issue?

Comment: I don't know of a logged issue specifically.  I was just suggesting that if there is one that relates to this, someone would post a link.  Of you could [go look yourself](https://bz.apache.org/).

Comment: Please specify how do you sum those cells

Comment: Edited to show most of the steps in the calculation. I am not sure how much more I am allowed to divulge.

Comment: For the time being, seeing as this is a sum of 4 other fields that are calculating correctly I'll just sum them outside of XL.  Still a frustrating problem.